# FB.getLoginStatus is responding (response.status=connected) at second click

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, share-button

I want to share my post to Facebook so i have written the code. but when I am clicking on my button, FB.getLoginStatus is responding "unknown" to response.status for the first time but responding "connected" if i click again.
here is my code:

```
$("#fb_share").on("click",function(){
  var poi_id    = $("#fb_share").attr('data-id');
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(statusResp) {
    console.log(statusResp);
    if (statusResp.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me?fields=email', function(response) {
            if(response.email){
                sendEventInvite(statusResp,response,poi_id);
            }else{
                FBLoginFirst(poi_id,statusResp,"detail");
            }
        });

    }else{
console.log("fb_permission_scope---"+fb_permission_scope);
        FBLoginFirst();
    }
});
});
```

this is what i get in console.log

```
Object { status="unknown",  authResponse=null}
```

this is what i get at second click

```
Object { status="connected",  authResponse={...}}`
```

Comment: Ive not used the FaceBook API but how are you authenticating against it? Are you sure your authenticated before clicking the button? May help others who have used it if you add some info on that.

Comment: yes!! I am calling window.fbAsyncInit function at very top of the page and it is giving result as well

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra equal sign (=) in your if statement. Three equal signs (===) is a correct operator when comparing something to a boolean value.

Try with this:

```
$("#fb_share").on("click",function(){
  var poi_id    = $("#fb_share").attr('data-id');
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(statusResp) {
    console.log(statusResp);
    if (statusResp.status == 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me?fields=email', function(response) {
            if(response.email){
                sendEventInvite(statusResp,response,poi_id);
            }else{
                FBLoginFirst(poi_id,statusResp,"detail");
            }
        });

    }else{
console.log("fb_permission_scope---"+fb_permission_scope);
        FBLoginFirst();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: well!! thanks for responding but error is coming on the third line on FB.getLoginStatus.. it isn't returning the value at first attempt but when responding at second, everything working smooth.

Comment: `===` Is for strict equality checking, not linked to checking directly against a Boolean value. It will stop the browser attempting to coerce the values on either side of the operator.

Comment: I have always thought that `===` cannot be used for checking string values but supposedly I'm wrong. Some programming languages are more forgiving than others.